# How can I render a cObj or any cObj from any page but from an eID-ajax function on a specific page?

Tags: typo3

In an eID script I want to render all the content elements of a specific page with the function cObjGetSingle but it gives me an empty string? My code:

```
tslib_eidtools::connectDB(); //Connect to database
$cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$conf['tables'] = 'tt_content';
$conf['source'] = "551"; 
$conf['dontCheckPid'] = 1;
return $cObj->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', $conf);
```

EDIT: There is a problem in class.tslib_content.php in the function cObjGetSingle? The function doesn't get executed because there is a crazy recursion loop check? The code:

```
        // Checking that the function is not called eternally. This is done by interrupting at a depth of 100
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObjectDepthCounter--;
    if ($GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObjectDepthCounter > 0) {
        $name = trim($name);
```

When I call cObjGetSingle $GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObjectDepthCounter is null and after the check it's -1 so the function kills the loop. But why?

Edit 2: This doesn't solve the problem either: http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-dev/2007-August/024497.html? Here is my conf-Array:

```
    $conf = array (
                    'tables' => 'tt_content',
                    'source' => "551",
                    'dontCheckPid' => 1,
                    "conf." => array (
                            "tt_content" => "TEXT",
                                "tt_content." => array (
                                        "field" => 'uid'
                                    ),

                        )
                    );
```

Edit 3: According to the post I'm not sure if it is a  USER_INT / COA_INT or caching problem because the page I use this is uncached and I want to use an eID (ajax) function to render my content object??? I'm not sure how I can debug this?

Edit 4: Maybe the solutions is to create a cObj? http://www.mneuhaus.com/2008/12/05/function-to-make-a-cobj-in-typo3/????

Edit 5: Here is another shorter version: http://sebastiaandejonge.com/blog/articles/2010/september/21/bringing-ajax-to-your-frontend-plugins/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a rendering definition below conf!

Have a look into `tt_content` at `TSOB`. On a normal page, this is there. Now you have to do it manually.

Comment: Do you have an example? In my edit no 2 I've clearly stated a working conf? I'm also looking for how can I render the whole page in eID?

Comment: If you need full TS support, you better use a `page type` instead of the `eId` feature.